# How to use html webpages content in android Applications

Tags: android, html, flutter, web

[gfg web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3jfd.png)

[gfg app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/848ej.png)

Hey,
Here are the two images from the geeksforgeeks website and geeksforgeeks application, notice that they both have the same content, Now question is that how they uses the webpages content in his application, Is they save there articles content in the database and then fetch for both website and android application ? or they are using something else.

thanks in Advanced...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They aren't parsing html in textview or something, rather they have a server, and they make request, and they get response to the request (probably in form of JSON) and they have some fragment or activity with specific set of elements and they just parse JSON and extract content.

And again, there are MANY ways to do this, but am pretty sure they aren't just parsing HTML to textview or something. You can search and implement popular architecture in your app.